# Angular - Cannot find module 'ngx-pagination' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

In my Angular-15 project, I am implementing ngx-pagination.
So, since I'm making use of ngx-bootstrap itself, I did:

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap --save
```

Then in my AppModule, I did:

```
import { PaginationModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/pagination';
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination'; //Imports NgxPaginationModule
```

But I got this error:

> Cannot find module 'ngx-pagination' or its corresponding type declarations

Then ngx-pagination is highlighted in

```
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';
```

What could be wrong and how do I resolve this?

Thanks